# How to retrieve data of a certain child of a Node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[Firebase Database Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv5rB.png)
I have attached an image can you please tell me the query to retrieve that childs of "notification".

`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("notification").orderByChild("name")`

I have used above query but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is this another user's data or your own? Are you trying to find nodes named `"kydigxgo"` or just the nodes under `"notifications"`? Does `"kydigxgo"` change or is it always that name? (edit these answers into your question)

Comment: Please provide the information samthecodingman asked for, and please also please respond with @.